# About uniformly continuity for bounded and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\vert\parallel x\parallel<1\right\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an one-to-one bounded continuous function.
I want to construct such $f$ which is not uniformly continuous.
In this case, I thought I can construct $f$ with a restriction $n=2$.
But I'm confused because $f$ is bounded so I can't use functions like $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$.
To top that off, $f$ is even one-to-one so I gave up and now I'm writing this to get some help from you who is smarter than me.
Please give me some help to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For $n=1$, as pointed out by Vishal, there is no such function $f$.

For $n\geq 2$, such an $f$ doesn't exist either, but for a "trivial" reason: there is no continuous and one-to-one function at all from the open unit ball $B\subset\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R$. One can see this as follows. Assume that $f:B\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $1$-$1$. Then $I=f(B)$ is a nontrivial interval of $\mathbb R$ because $B$ is connected and $f$ is continuous and non-constant. Take any point $a\in B$ such that $f(a)$ is an interior point of $I$. Then $f(B\setminus\{ a\})$ has to be connected because $B\setminus\{ a\}$ is connected ($n\geq 2$) and $f$ is continuous. But $f(B\setminus\{ a\})$ is equal to $I\setminus \{ f(a)\}$ because $f$ is $1$-$1$, and this is not a connected set. So we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

At least for $n =1$, any such function will have a limit on the end points $-1,1$ in this case and hence will have an extension on the interval $[-1,1]$ and hence will be uniformly continuous. So, you cannot construct a function you want in the case $n=1$.

For higher dimensions, the main thing is to examine whether the limit exists on the boundary of the closed ball (in the case $n=1$ one-one and continuity implies monotonicity, which gives the limit). If there is a limit, then the function will again be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct such function. You can prove that $f$ has the limit on the boundary of the closed ball and $f$ will be uniformly continuous.

Let $U_n$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $f$ on the interval $[0,x)\subset U_n$ that connects the center of the ball and the point $x$ from the edge of the ball (i.e. $\|x\|=1$). Now we consider $f$ only $[0,x)$ and using that we can consider $f$ as a function of one variable: $f(y)=f(tx), t\in[0,1)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,x)$ and one-to-one then it is monotonic and hence has the limit at $x$.

Actually, I must take any curve $C$, that connects the center of the ball and the point $x$, instead of $[0,x)$. But that case is proven similarly.